# Xceed PropertyGrid AdvancedOptionsMenu context menu example

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I'm trying to get a "Copy" context menu to display when clicking on the advanced options icon of any property. What do I need to add to make it work?

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid
        x:Name="PropertyGrid"  
        Grid.Column="1" Margin="8"
        ShowSummary="False"    
        AutoGenerateProperties="True" 
        HideInheritedProperties="False"
        SelectedObject="{Binding InspectedObject}"
        SelectedObjectName="{Binding InspectedObject, Converter={StaticResource PropertyGridPropertyNameConverter}}"
        SelectedObjectTypeName="{Binding InspectedObject, Converter={StaticResource PropertyGridPropertyTypeConverter}}"
        SelectedObjectChanged="PropertyGrid_OnSelectedObjectChanged"
        ShowAdvancedOptions="True"

    >
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.AdvancedOptionsMenu >
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Click="MenuItem_OnClick"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.AdvancedOptionsMenu>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

I'd like the "Copy" context item to display and take a click whether or not the property is read only.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? Can you share? Thanks :)

Comment: No, sorry I haven't addressed it yet - I've been putting off having to work around this by either making the properties writable  or making custom controls which would allow copying (I have lots of properties)

Comment: @IgorMF I forked the original repo and I have added copy value menu item to AdvancedOptionsMenu. Check it out: https://github.com/kmatyaszek/wpftoolkit

Answer (score 2):

In the MenuItem click event handler, you can access property data by property DataContext in sender object.

```
private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null && menuItem.DataContext is PropertyItem)
    {
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, ((PropertyItem)menuItem.DataContext).Value);
    }
}
```

In the following link, you can find more information about this topic:
https://kmatyaszek.github.io/2018/08/22/extended-wpftoolkit-propertygrid-copybutton.html

I have noticed that this solution works when you clicked (left mouse button) at AdvancedOptionsMenu icon, there is a problem with the right mouse click on the property item. To solve this problem I forked the original repo and I have added copy value menu item to AdvancedOptionsMenu. Check it out: [https://github.com/kmatyaszek/wpftoolkit](https://github.com/kmatyaszek/wpftoolkit/commit/2ebf84cab19bdbdb01f5350e434319c8dc7fa524)

Comment: @Gaspa79 I have changed the blog engine. Please read this post on the following site: https://kmatyaszek.github.io/2018/08/22/extended-wpftoolkit-propertygrid-copybutton.html